# Connecting two tikz pictures with arrow

Tags: latex, drawing, tex, tikz

I am trying to draw an arrow to link these two pictures and demonstrate the rotation. Can I do this with this minipage idea or do I need to draw them differently?

[image: Rotation function g]

```
\begin{minipage}{0,5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,2)--(0,-2);
\draw (-2,0)--(2,0);
\newdimen\R
\R=1.5cm
   \draw (36:\R)
   \foreach \x in {36,108,180,252,324} {  -- (\x:\R) }
 -- cycle (36:\R) node[right] {4}
-- cycle (108:\R) node[above] {5}
 -- cycle (180:\R) node[below] {1}
-- cycle  (252:\R) node[below] {2}           -- cycle  (324:\R) node[right] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}{0,5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,2)--(0,-2);
\draw (-2,0)--(2,0);
\newdimen\R
\R=1.5cm
   \draw (36:\R)
   \foreach \x in {36,108,180,252,324} {  -- (\x:\R) }
 -- cycle (36:\R) node[right] {3}
-- cycle (108:\R) node[above] {4}
 -- cycle (180:\R) node[below] {5}
-- cycle  (252:\R) node[below] {1}           -- cycle  (324:\R) node[right] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 3):

In theory you could use the `tikzmark` library to draw arrows between your two minipages, but I think it is easier to just put both drawing in a single `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
  \draw (0,2)--(0,-2);
  \draw (-2,0)--(2,0);
  \newdimen\R
  \R=1.5cm
     \draw (36:\R)
     \foreach \x in {36,108,180,252,324} {  -- (\x:\R) }
   -- cycle (36:\R) node[right] {4}
  -- cycle (108:\R) node[above] {5}
   -- cycle (180:\R) node[below] {1}
  -- cycle  (252:\R) node[below] {2}           -- cycle  (324:\R) node[right] {3};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
  \draw (0,2)--(0,-2);
  \draw (-2,0)--(2,0);
  \newdimen\R
  \R=1.5cm
     \draw (36:\R)
     \foreach \x in {36,108,180,252,324} {  -- (\x:\R) }
   -- cycle (36:\R) node[right] {3}
  -- cycle (108:\R) node[above] {4}
   -- cycle (180:\R) node[below] {5}
  -- cycle  (252:\R) node[below] {1}           -- cycle  (324:\R) node[right] {2};
\end{scope}

\draw[red,<->] (2.3,0) -- (3.8,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Agreed, the environment "scope" fits perfectly here :)