# Draw arrow between two tikz pictures

Tags: latex, beamer, tikz

I want to draw an arrow from one tikzpicture to another, to include in my Beamer presentation I am making in Rmarkdown. I tried following the answer to this question: [Connecting two tikz pictures with arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65369473/connecting-two-tikz-pictures-with-arrow). However, it does not work for me as it connects the two images together instead. This is my initial code (to make it fit with bullet points in the slide):

Edit: I have inlcuded my YAML in Rmarkdown.

```
---
title: "This title must be included in the first slide but is very very long"
subtitle: "Masters Thesis presentation"
institute: "My school"
author: First Last
date: March 2022
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    theme: "Madrid"
header-includes:
   - \AtBeginDocument{\title[short title for footline]{This title must be included in the first slide but is very very long}}
   - \usepackage{tikz}
   - \usepackage{subfig}
   - \usepackage{natbib}
   - \usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, calc}
   - \usepackage{algorithm}
   - \usepackage{algpseudocode}
   - \usepackage{caption}
   - \captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
   - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   - \usepackage{graphics}
   - \usepackage{amsmath}
   - \usepackage{bm}
---
# Recode to three states

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{% 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every state/.style={minimum width={2cm} ,thick,align=center}]
  \node[state] (1) {1: DEAD};
  \node[state] at (3, 2) (3) {3:VFT};
  \node[state] at (6, 0) (5) {5:ROSC};
  \node[state] at (1.5, -3.3) (2) {2:ASY};
  \node[state] at (4.5, -3.3) (4) {4:PEA};
  
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,above] {} (2);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (4) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
\end{figure}


\column{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{figure}%[H]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.6\textwidth}{!}{% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, scale=1, 
    transform shape, align=center, 
    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]

    \node[state] at (0,0) (5) {5:ROSC};  
    \node[state] at (3,-2) (1) {1:DEAD};
    \node[state] at (3,2) (2) {2:PEASY};

    \path[->] (5) edge node {$h_{51}$} (1)
              (5) edge node {$h_{52}$} (2)
              (2) edge node {$h_{21}$} (1)
              (2) edge [bend left] node [right] {$h_{25}$} (5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\end{figure}
\end{columns}

Steps to recode:

>- Combine states 2 and 4 into state 2
>- Write function that discards redundant rows (2 $\rightarrow$ 2)
>- Delete `from` = 3 rows
>- Expand dataset to keep censored cases
>- Delete `to` = 3 rows
```

[Image of the original tikzpictures without arrow between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzmqM.png)
Which works, but does not have an arrow between the two tikzpictures.

Here is what I tried following the answer of the link I provided above, where I tried putting the images into one tikzpicture and using scopes.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every state/.style={minimum width={2cm} ,thick,align=center}]

\begin{scope}
  \node[state] (1) {1: DEAD};
  \node[state] at (3, 2) (3) {3:VFT};
  \node[state] at (6, 0) (5) {5:ROSC};
  \node[state] at (1.5, -3.3) (2) {2:ASY};
  \node[state] at (4.5, -3.3) (4) {4:PEA};
  
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,above] {} (2);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (4) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
\end{scope}



\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \node[state] at (0,0) (5) {5:ROSC};  
    \node[state] at (3,-2) (1) {1:DEAD};
    \node[state] at (3,2) (2) {2:PEASY};
    \path[->] (5) edge node {$h_{51}$} (1)
              (5) edge node {$h_{52}$} (2)
              (2) edge node {$h_{21}$} (1)
              (2) edge [bend left] node [right] {$h_{25}$} (5);
\end{scope}

\draw[red,->] (6,0) -- (10,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

For some reason the pictures are now connected through the one node called 5: ROSC.
[Image of the wrong tikzpicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOYOf.png)

I want the two original tikzpictures with an arrow going between them, preferrably at the height of the 5:ROSC node.

Edit 2: I have included an image of what I would like the arrow to look like. [image: Image of arrow between the two tikzpictures]

Comment: I would use a `tikzmark`. Can you make a compilable [mre] so we don't have to guess the necessary packages and libraries?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz absolutely. I thought I had, but I will include the YAML from Rmarkdown too

Comment: Thanks for adding the necessary libraries (and more). A couple of comments: you don't need `graphics` or `amsmath`, beamer already loads them. If you already use the caption package, I would use `subcaption` instead of `subfig`. If you've updated your tex distribution sometime within the last 5 years  or so, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Haha yes, I just included all the packages I need for the entire presentation, just in case some of the packages were needed. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The point is, you don't need these packages for any presentation.

Comment: A quick way to do this is to put both drawings in the same tikz figure, but shift one (or both) using \begin{scope}[shift=...] Then, you can just draw the arrow as one normally would.  The solutions below are more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `tikzmark`s for this job:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape,every state/.style={minimum width={2cm} ,thick,align=center},state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]
  \node[state] (1) {1: DEAD};
  \node[state] at (3, 2) (3) {3:VFT};
  \node[state] at (6, 0) (5) {\tikzmark{foo}5:ROSC};
  \node[state] at (1.5, -3.3) (2) {2:ASY};
  \node[state] at (4.5, -3.3) (4) {4:PEA};
  
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,above] {} (2);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (4) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, scale=1, 
    transform shape, align=center, 
    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]

    \node[state] at (0,0) (5) {5:ROSC};  
    \node[state] at (3,-2) (1) {1:DEAD};
    \node[state] at (3,2) (2) {\tikzmark{bar}2:PEASY};

    \path[->] (5) edge node {$h_{51}$} (1)
              (5) edge node {$h_{52}$} (2)
              (2) edge node {$h_{21}$} (1)
              (2) edge [bend left] node [right] {$h_{25}$} (5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,->] (pic cs:foo) -- (pic cs:bar);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

(needs at least two compilations to get the coordinates right)

---

Here the same in rmarkdown:

```
---
title: "This title must be included in the first slide but is very very long"
subtitle: "Masters Thesis presentation"
institute: "My school"
author: First Last
date: March 2022
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    theme: "Madrid"
header-includes:
   - \AtBeginDocument{\title[short title for footline]{This title must be included in the first slide but is very very long}}
   - \usepackage{tikz}
   - \usepackage{subfig}
   - \usepackage{natbib}
   - \usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, calc,tikzmark}
   - \usepackage{algorithm}
   - \usepackage{algpseudocode}
   - \usepackage{caption}
   - \captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
   - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   - \usepackage{graphics}
   - \usepackage{amsmath}
   - \usepackage{bm}
---
# Recode to three states

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape,every state/.style={minimum width={2cm} ,thick,align=center},state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]
  \node[state] (1) {1: DEAD};
  \node[state] at (3, 2) (3) {3:VFT};
  \node[state] at (6, 0) (5) {\tikzmark{foo}5:ROSC};
  \node[state] at (1.5, -3.3) (2) {2:ASY};
  \node[state] at (4.5, -3.3) (4) {4:PEA};
  
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,above] {} (2);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (4) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, scale=1, 
    transform shape, align=center, 
    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]

    \node[state] at (0,0) (5) {5:ROSC};  
    \node[state] at (3,-2) (1) {1:DEAD};
    \node[state] at (3,2) (2) {\tikzmark{bar}2:PEASY};

    \path[->] (5) edge node {$h_{51}$} (1)
              (5) edge node {$h_{52}$} (2)
              (2) edge node {$h_{21}$} (1)
              (2) edge [bend left] node [right] {$h_{25}$} (5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,->] (pic cs:foo) -- (pic cs:bar);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Update

As your new sketch does not show any interaction at all between your arrow and your images, just add a third column:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape,every state/.style={minimum width={2cm} ,thick,align=center},state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]
  \node[state] (1) {1: DEAD};
  \node[state] at (3, 2) (3) {3:VFT};
  \node[state] at (6, 0) (5) {5:ROSC};
  \node[state] at (1.5, -3.3) (2) {2:ASY};
  \node[state] at (4.5, -3.3) (4) {4:PEA};
  
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,above] {} (2);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<-] (1) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (3);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (2) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (4);
  \draw[<->] (3) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  
  \draw[<->] (4) -- node [midway,below] {} (5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.1\textwidth}
\tikz\draw[blue,->] (0,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,transform shape, >=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, scale=1, 
    transform shape, align=center, 
    state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]

    \node[state] at (0,0) (5) {5:ROSC};  
    \node[state] at (3,-2) (1) {1:DEAD};
    \node[state] at (3,2) (2) {2:PEASY};

    \path[->] (5) edge node {$h_{51}$} (1)
              (5) edge node {$h_{52}$} (2)
              (2) edge node {$h_{21}$} (1)
              (2) edge [bend left] node [right] {$h_{25}$} (5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's close to what I want, but I just need a simple horizontal line between the two tikzpictures, not directly from one node to another. As a way to describe that we go from the first image to the next image.

Comment: @jooliburger Something like `\draw[red,->] (pic cs:foo) -- ++(4cm,0);`?

Comment: Does the Rmarkdown file compile for you? I keep getting this error message: "!Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate." No matter which coordinates I use

Comment: @jooliburger Yes it works fine for me. Both with TL2022 (pretest) and TL2021